# How does one handle scope identity statements in T-SQL T?

Tags: tsqlt

There doesn't seem to be any way to Fake a table then have the SCOPE_IDENTITY function run on the faked table.

Take this statement (inside a stored procedure)

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SomeTable](Id1, Id2) 
VALUES (@Id1, @Id2)

SET @SomeIdentity =  SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2](Id3)
VALUES(@SomeIdentity)
```

So if I try and test this block of code

I'll fake the table [SomeTable] like this

```
EXEC [tSQLt].[FakeTable] @TableName = N'[SomeTable]',
        @SchemaName = N'dbo',
        @Identity = 0,
        @ComputedColumns = 1,
        @Defaults = 1

EXEC [tSQLt].[FakeTable] @TableName = N'[Table2]',
        @SchemaName = N'dbo',
        @Identity = 0,
        @ComputedColumns = 1,
        @Defaults = 1
```

However when it comes to test the block of code with the scope identity column, the Id3 is always null.

I've attempted identity = 0 or 1 but T-SQL doesn't seem to handle this scenario..

Has anyone solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `@identity` parameter to 1 to preserve the identity column when using `tSQLt.FakeTable`:

```
EXEC [tSQLt].[FakeTable] 
    @TableName = N'dbo.[SomeTable]',
    @Identity = 1,
    @ComputedColumns = 1,
    @Defaults = 1
```

(Note: the @SchemaName parameter is deprecated.)

Comment: Hi Sebastian.. thanks for your answer. Yes I tried that.. and that it didn't work because in that scenario we don't expect that the id is going to be populated with SCOPE_IDENTITY, we expect that we will populate every other column with data and get an autogenerated id.. In T-sqlt when using scope identity the id of the faked table seems always to be null.